# Changing order of derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I would like to rewrite the following expression

$$\frac{d^i}{dx^i}\left\{f(x)\left[\frac{d^jf(x)}{dx^j}\right]\left[\frac{d^kf(x)}{dx^k}\right]\right\}$$

into the form

$$D f(x)^3,$$

with $D$ being an unknown differential operator (to be determined).

$f(x)$ is a real-valued function.

Comment: And $f^3(x)$ is $f(x)^3$, not $f(f(f(x)))$?

Comment: I suspect this isn't possible. What operators other than $\mathrm d^{i+j+k}/\mathrm dx^{i+j+k}$ could occur in $D$?

Comment: well, to give you a simple example, $f(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)^2}{2}$. so i need some kind of generalization of this procedure. $D$ can contain anything, I am just interested in moving the functions $f$ to the right

Comment: one idea would be to use the [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Generalizations) to distribute the derivatives, but then one is still left with products of derivatives of $f$

Comment: "$D$ can contain anything" is a bit vague. Can $D$ be the operator whose action is "take the third root, multiply the result by its $j$-th and $k$-th derivatives, then differentiate $i$ times"? If not, how do you distinguish that from the anything that $D$ can contain? Perhaps you want $D$ to contain only linear operations?

Comment: I want it to contain only derivatives, sums and products of derivatives of various orders

Answer (score 1):

I'll take your comment that you want $D$ "to contain only derivatives, sums and products of derivatives of various orders" at face value, and I'll throw in real-valued coefficients, too. Then what you want is impossible.

Any such expression can be multiplied out to obtain a linear combination of derivatives of various orders. To have the right behaviour under scaling of $x$, the operator can only contain the derivative of order $i+j+k$. (Another way to think about this is to "check the units/dimensions", with each derivative contributing an inverse unit of length). But clearly you can't get all the expressions you want to represent just from scalar multiples of the derivative of order $i+j+k$.